# музыкальный плеер на сайте

Tags: php, javascript

Здравствуйте! Хочу создать музыкальный сайт, просмотрел достаточно много книг но так и не нашёл как связать php,базы данные  с музыкальным плеером (скачал с зарубежно ресурса). подскажите какую нибудь литературу... или объясните как можно сделать так чтоб у меня был плейлист в который попадают песни через форму загрузки и по нажитию на песню всё это дело воспроизводилось

Answer (score 1):

Разбейте на отдельные задачи.

Начните с плеера. Положите на ваш сайт одну mp3'шку и сделайте страницу, на которой она проиграется. Проще всего, вероятно, с помощью html5 элемента [`<audio>`](http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_audio.asp).

Comment: Можно по подробнее?

Comment: http://htmlbook.ru/html/audio